# Remove border of tkinter button created with an image

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a couple of buttons using my program and I've made them include images. However, I wish to now remove the border that remains (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/K128c.png for screenshot).

The code for the "back" button as an example:

```
backbutton = ttk.Button(mainframe, command=homereturn)
backbuttonimage = PhotoImage(file="back.gif")
backbutton.config(image=backbuttonimage)
backbutton.pack()
backbutton.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having a similar problem, but only on a Raspberry Pi.  Works great on Windows. I'm using tk.Button with borderwidth=0 and still getting outlines.  I see similar outlines around my sliders in this example:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13696193/43404372-580639e6-93e5-11e8-9fa1-7841daca2dba.jpg

Answer (score 17):

```
backbutton = tk.Button(...,  highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
```

This works for Python 3.x, I tried...

[image]

```
 icon = PhotoImage(file="lock.png")
 self.company_lock_button = Button(self.control_lock_frame, image = icon, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
 self.day_lock_button = Button(self.control_lock_frame, image = icon)
 self.hour_lock_button = Button(self.control_lock_frame, image = icon)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using images to define a custom button, use the standard button class rather than the ttk button class. This will allow you to set the borderwidth attribute to zero:

```
import tkinter as tk
...
backbutton = tk.Button(..., borderwidth=0)
```

(unrelated: there's no point in calling `backbutton.pack()` and immediately follow it with `backbutton.grid(...)` - you can only use one for a particular widget, and the last one you call is the one that has any effect. In this case the call to `pack` is completely useless)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with imaged buttons. Neither `bd=0` nor `highlichtthickness=0` *alone* helped. I even suspected the `relief`-option to play it's part.

What finally helped me: `pady=0, padx=0`

So, for the question asked:

```py
backbutton.config(image=backbuttonimage, highlightthickness=0, pady=0, padx=0)
```

could work.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it mentions padding.

Answer (score 2):

Using a new Mac I had the same issue and none of the other answers fully removed the border surrounding the button. I found that setting `highlightbackground` to the canvas's background color did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use highlightthickness=0 and bd=0

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions provided so far worked in my case.

(I can only suspect that this is related to the new MacOS GUI style policy of recent versions (I'm using Big Sur). Also other style options don't work on MacOS, e.g. the relief option doesn't have any effect on the appearance of a button.)

Here is my solution: when you put an image to a button, the options *width* and *height* take pixels as unit. When you chose small values, i.e. 10x10, the border seems to be covered by the image. Voilá!

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, none of these seemed to work.
In photo editing software (Photoshop):
Create the button image with the same color background as you intend to set your tkinter window to. Also make sure your button image background is at least a few pixels larger than the image.

In your code:
Reduce the size of the button by a few pixels. Test by clicking on your button. If you notice the outline reappearing, reduce it some more. Here the original file "button.png" was 100x40 pixels.

```
# Set the background color to whatever you want
# This is the color value for "Dark" windows on a Mac.
root.configure(bg="#323232")
my_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="button.png")
button = tk.Button(root, image=my_image, width=96, height=36)
button.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it..

Use `ttk.Style()` to set the button's background color to the color of mainframe.

```
root_color = "red" #Just an example, can't remember the default tk window color

mainframe = tk.Tk() #or whatever mainframe is
mainframe.configure(bg = root_color)
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TButton', background = root_color)
backbutton = ttk.Button(mainframe, command=homereturn)
backbuttonimage=PhotoImage(file="back.gif")
backbutton.config(image=backbuttonimage)
backbutton.pack()
backbutton.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

As a side note, you don't have to specify `style = ..` in your ttk button here because you are configuring the default `TButton` style ttk uses. If you defined a custom style for this button you would have to specify this in the keyword arguements for the button.

An example would be giving your button rounded edges instead of using images to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Cheers, that's cool - but what if I plan to give the mainframe a background image?

Comment: Using pack() and then grid() is pointless since they can't be combined.  It'll only use grid() in this case since that's what you called last.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `import` function as:

```py
from tkinter import *

Button(main_scr, text = "OK", bg = "yellow", bd = 0, command = delete1).pack()
```

The `bd = 0` would not show the border.

Comment: While helpful, that's not how they're creating the button in the Q and the answer would be more helpful if it considered that context.

Answer (score 0):

Not all themes support changing `borderwidth`. Try using `tkinter.tk` instead of using `ttk.Button`.

Use keyword `borderwidth=0` for Button's parameter.

You cannot use both `backbutton.pack()` and `backbutton.grid()`. You can select one of them.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
 

mainframe = tk.Tk()
              
def homereturn():
    print('hello')

backbutton = tk.Button(mainframe, command=homereturn, borderwidth=0)
backbuttonimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
backbutton.config(image=backbuttonimage)
backbutton.pack()
 
mainframe.mainloop()
```

Screenshot w/out border:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

padding='0,0,0,0'

CODE:

ttk.Button( frame, text='B', image='myimg.png', padding='0,0,0,0', command=my_cmd)

Sorry, that it comes how many years later.