# Make edges of button disappear in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a customized button, on which I loaded an icon like this:
[image]

but as you can see there's a "box" around the button. The icon itself doesn't have background, so I guess the box is added by tkinter to indicate that this is a button. Is there a way to make those four lines disappear?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060837/remove-tkinter-button-border

Comment: @Stidgeon Thanks man but none of them seem to work...I can't use the ttk one for other reasons though.

Comment: On OSX there's nothing much you can do about buttons. Try using a label.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks!